# Insert response data into table

Tags: angularjs, json

Response :

```
    {
    "json": {
      "response": {
        "servicetype": "1",
        "functiontype": "1000",
        "statuscode": "0",
        "statusmessage": "Success",
        "data": [{
            "groupzname": "NARAYANA E-SCHOOL1",
            "groupzcode": "CHATCH",
            "area": "JAYANAGARA 9TH BLOCK",
            "city": "BENGALURU",
            "state": "Karnataka",
            "country": "INDIA"
          },

          {
            "shortname": "School",
            "groupzname": "Smitha School",
            "groupzcode": "4353",
            "area": "fsdfsdf",
            "city": "sdfsf",
            "state": "vxcvxv",
            "country": "vxcvxv"
          }, {
            "shortname": "SerReq",
            "groupzname": "Service R",
            "groupzcode": "SerReq",
            "area": "SerReq",
            "city": "SerReq",
            "state": "SerReq",
            "country": "SerReq"
          }, {
            "shortname": "service",
            "groupzname": "Service Gropz",
            "groupzcode": "1111",
            "area": "jayanagar",
            "city": "bangalore",
            "state": "Karnataka",
            "country": "India"
          }, {
            "shortname": "Testing",
            "groupzname": "Smitha Groupz",
            "groupzcode": "5555",
            "area": "jayanagar 9th block",
            "city": "Bangalore",
            "state": "Karnataka",
            "country": "India"
          },

          {
            "shortname": "May12R2",
            "groupzname": "May12Release2",
            "groupzcode": "May12R2",
            "area": "May12R2Area: ",
            "city": "May12City",
            "state": "May12State",
            "country": "May12Country"
          }, {
            "shortname": "May12",
            "groupzname": "May12Release",
            "groupzcode": "May12",
            "area": "May12 Area",
            "city": "May12 city",
            "state": "May12 State",
            "country": "May12 Country"
          }, {
            "shortname": "Kank",
            "groupzname": "Kankar",
            "groupzcode": "knakr12",
            "area": "Kankar Area",
            "city": "Kankar city",
            "state": "Kankar state",
            "country": "Kankarcountry"
          }, {
            "shortname": "Hir",
            "groupzname": "Heera",
            "groupzcode": "Hir001",
            "area": "Hir are",
            "city": "Hir cit",
            "state": "Hir State",
            "country": "Hir India"
          },

          {
            "shortname": "Apr",
            "groupzname": "Aparajitha",
            "groupzcode": "Apraj20",
            "area": "apar area",
            "city": "apar city",
            "state": "apar state",
            "country": "apar indi"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

I have to  insert the above shortname, groupzname,groupzcode, area,city,country etc from this response to table dynamically.

JS :

```
     $scope.viewAccount = function(){
                   $scope.showListAccount = true;

              var json = {

  "json": {
    "request": {
      "servicetype": "6",
      "functiontype": "6014",
      "session_id": $rootScope.currentSession,
           "data": {
        "sortbasedon": $scope.groupzname,
        "orderby": "desc",
        "limit":10,
        "offset":10
           }

    }
  }
};

          UserService.viewListAccount(json).then(function(response) {



                 if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage == 'Success')

                     $scope.dataArray = response.json.response.data;



                        $scope.myname = $scope.dataArray.shortname;
                        console.log($scope.myname);


            }); 
        };
```

If I pass above request and console the data ,  facing error which keep on incrementing. angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

Comment: so what is the error you see ? parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to display into table.

```
<table>                
    <tr>
        <th>groupzcode</th>
        <th>area</th>
        <th>city</th>
        <th>state</th>
        <th>country</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="data in output.json.response.data">
            <td>{{ data.shortname}}</td>
            <td>{{data.groupzname}}</td>
            <td>{{data.groupzcode}}</td>
            <td>{{data.area}}</td>
            <td>{{data.city}}</td>
            <td>{{data.state}}</td>
            <td>{{data.country}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

output is the json output.

Comment: Hi , I did so . But facing error which keep on incrementing. angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

Comment: If you had used exact json file you posted, notice that ,output.json.response.data[0] does not contain output.json.response.data[0].shortname,

Comment: Include that and It should work fine. And , for your query that scope variable can be used in table, yes , it can.

Comment: Dont I wanna do anything in my JS part for doing above code. I am kind of new

Comment: replace 'output.json.response.data' with your scope variable. In js write,$scope.tableData = output.json.response.data and replace data-ng-repeat="data in output.json.response.data" with data-ng-repeat="data in tableData" in above code.

Comment: Thanks a lot S kumar. I really understood what is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In controller,

store the required json data in object;

```
$scope.arrRec = output.json.response.data
```

This will cause two way data binding.Whenever the data is changes it get automatically reflected in view.

In the view, use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive,

e.g. for using div.

```
<div ng-repeat="oneRec in arrRec"  >
 {{oneRec.groupzname}}  {{oneRec.groupzcode}}{{oneRec.area}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi , Is it possible to use the same in table too ?

Comment: angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []  I get this error when I do So

Comment: @NicoletaWilskon please share the script generating this json.The probelm look like there

Answer (score -1):

As angular is MVC framework, you don't worry updates between views and model, all is done by controller automatically.

Comment: He needed a little guidance in doing the work he asked for. Although there are multiple solutions out there but it will be better if you point him in the right direction. Your answer is not sufficient for a newbie I guess